# At what point should data be sent back to server?

Tags: ajax, dynamic-forms

A good example would be the stackexchange "rate" button. When a post is upvoted the arrow changes color immediately. However there is a grace period for one to edit one's vote decision (oops! voted by mistake?). Is the upvote action processed immediately or does is only process after a set time period, or when the user leaves the page? How exactly is this rating processed?

What is the standard for handling dynamic page edits (e.g. stackexchange rating, facebook posts?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I would recommend that you make the changes immediately. If there's to be a "grace period", then implement that on the server side (you can do it client side too if it will improve user experience).

So if someone upvotes a post, it is saved immediately via ajas, but then if they change their minds within the grace period, the server undoes the vote. Once the "grace period" is up, the server rejects the change.

A Facebook post would (obviously) be saved when you click "Post", etc. -- but it wouldn't be saved before then.

Something like Blogger or Google Docs is another issue altogether -- where it's automatic saving every x number of seconds. That is purely up to the developer. Generally you want to make it as often as possible without impacting performance or decreasing the user experience.